# log in to a website using Python's Requests module doesn't work on this site but work on other site

Tags: python

use the following code on twitter and github it work fine but it doesn't work on the main site i am using it for, can someone please tell me what went wrong.
i did not get any error instead it scrap back the login page instead of log me.

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
params = {'j_username': '**********', 'j_password': '************'}
r = requests.post("https://connect.data.com/loginProcess", params)
print("Cookie is set to:")
print(r.cookies.get_dict())
print("-----------")
print("Going to profile page...")
r = requests.get("https://connect.data.com/home")

print(r.text)
```

I am new to this so i can't figure out what went wrong, i have try many answer out before asking the question but none seem to workout for the site.
The login url is /login but the file that the login is been process is /loginProcess that is why i use /loginProcess but loginProcess does not print out my cookie but /login does print it out
The form to the site look like this:

```
<form id="command" name="LoginForm" action="https://connect.data.com/loginProcess" method="post">

            <div>
                <div class="login-container fields float-left">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="first">
                            <span class="title">Login</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="middle">
                            <input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="email" class="text" placeholder="Email" maxlength="128" tabindex="1">

                        </div>
                        <div class="middle">
                            <input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" class="text" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" maxlength="128">

                        </div>

                        <div class="middle">
                            <label for="_spring_security_remember_me" class="general-checkbox-label">
                                <input name="_spring_security_remember_me" tabindex="3" value="on" id="_spring_security_remember_me" class="checkbox margin-0px" type="checkbox">
                                <span>Keep me logged in </span>
                            </label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="last">

 <button id="login_btn" type="submit" class="button-standard button-primary" tabindex="4">


<span class="button-standard-text">Login</span>

</button>&nbsp;
                            <a class="link" href="https://connect.data.com/forgotpassword" onclick="var x=&quot;.tl(&quot;;s_objectID=&quot;https://connect.data.com/forgotpassword_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">Forgot Password?</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="login-container marketing-message float-right">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>
                            Don't have an account?  
                            Sign up now - it's FREE!
                        </h2>
                        <div class="float-left">
                            <img class="login-bicons" src="./Data.com Connect Business Contact Directory of Business Contacts and Company Information_files/clear.cache.gif">
                        </div>
                        <div class="float-left margin-left-20px">
                            <p>
                                <span id="pageTitle" style="color: #146791">Find</span> 
                                business card information &amp; B2B professionals. 
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <span id="pageTitle" style="color: #87c540">Research</span> 
                                people &amp; companies.
                            </p>
                            <p class="margin-top-5px">
                                <span id="pageTitle" style="color: #f37521">Get</span> 
                                millions of contacts.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="clear nonlogged-container-foot">
                    <span class="new-to-ddc">New to Data.com?</span>
                    <a class="sign-up" href="https://connect.data.com/registration/signup" onclick="var x=&quot;.tl(&quot;;s_objectID=&quot;https://connect.data.com/registration/signup_1&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">Sign up for an account...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="CSRF_TOKEN" id="CSRF_TOKEN" value="ce56932e08fc97bc29c5f6535b572664a66000513143584504b0ee7c66ef9659"></form>
```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: i did not get any error instead it scrap back the login page instead of log me in

Comment: can you try to print(r.text) after the first request performed?

Comment: after try that i got back the same login page

Comment: Here is an idea. Get login page and extract the CSRF token. Include that in the params e.g. `CSRF_TOKEN: <some_token>`. Make a `POST` request using the params to the login endpoint and see if this changes anything.

Comment: i have try that before it does not  work,